# BASH - How can I send them to dialogue only standard output and to file /root/sh/sh.log standard output + output error

Tags: bash, shell

Good day

How can I send them to dialogue only standard output and to file /root/sh/sh.log standard output + output error

```
# I need
dialog          == standard output
/root/sh/sh.log == standard output + error output 

# My experimental
start 2>&1 /root/sh/menu.log | dialog --stdout --progressbox 20 200;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like
start 2>> /root/sh/sh.log | tee -a /root/sh/sh.log | dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `tee` command and process substitution

```
{ start | tee >( dialog --stdout --progressbox 20 200) ; } > /root/sh/menu.log 2>&1
```

Within the command group, the standard output is passed to `tee`, which writes to a "file" that is actually a process substitution construct which passed its input to the `dialog` command. Think of it as a forked pipe for standard output.

Because standard error is not redirected, and `tee` passes its input back to standard output, both are passed out of the command group. First, we redirect standard output to the desired log file, then we duplicate standard error to wherever standard output is.

Comment: I've made a couple of edits to fix the `bash`-related portions; I don't have `start` or `dialog` to test with those commands specifically.